# query dropbox API to search files by metadata

Tags: dropbox, dropbox-api

I need to search Dropbox image files by a specific "tag" on my metadata for that file.

So, for example, I have photos of cats, the metadata will be

> catColor, catSize, catName

can I query the images to return all pics where

> catColor = Black

Is this possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Dropbox API does offer the ability to set custom metadata on files, via the use of the "file properties" feature:

https://www.dropbox.com/developers/documentation/http/documentation#file_properties

For instance, you would first define a property template, e.g., with 'catColor', 'catSize', and 'catName' fields, using:

https://www.dropbox.com/developers/documentation/http/documentation#file_properties-templates-add_for_user

Then, you can add values for that template to specific files using:

https://www.dropbox.com/developers/documentation/http/documentation#file_properties-properties-add

And then you can later search for files based on those values using:

https://www.dropbox.com/developers/documentation/http/documentation#file_properties-properties-search

By the way, those are links to the documentation for the HTTPS endpoints themselves, but we recommend using one of the official SDKs if possible:

https://www.dropbox.com/developers/documentation

Those have corresponding native methods for the HTTPS endpoints.